# Why is my script for calculating bank interest returned NONE?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Interest(balances,rate):
    for i in range(len(balances)):
        balances[i] = balances[i] * (1+rate)
def main():
    amounts = [1000,500]
    rate = 0.05
    amounts = Interest(amounts,rate)
    print(amounts)

main()
```

I tried to write a script to calculate the bank interest of a list, but it always returned None. I could not understand why this happened.

Comment: You need to use the `return` statement in order for your function to return anything. Here you would need to add `return balances` to your `Interest` function.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Because you don't return anything, so your functions return `None`.

Comment: What do you expect the function to return?

Answer (score 0):

No need to return anything just do this. Python changes the amounts when you pass it as a parameter.

```
def Interest(balances,rate):
    for i in range(len(balances)):
        balances[i] = balances[i] * (1+rate)
def main():
    amounts = [1000,500]
    print(amounts)
    rate = 0.05
    Interest(amounts,rate)
    print(amounts)
    
main()
```

Comment: I mean yeah, this works, but you are relying on the mutability of `list`s for your outcome. When OP tries this with something else, such as an `int` or string, it will just make it more confusing.

Comment: He'd be better of using a temp array and than returning that otherwise if he doesn't want to change the original.

Comment: Well, you *can* do it this way, but it is better practice *not* to mutate the inputs